# Would full but not archive node delete old trie node from LVLDB?

Tags: state-trie

Full not archive node would store the nearest 128 block's state in their lvldb. How could they delete old trie state in lvldb? I found they use dereference function in WriteBlockWithState function to delete it in cached triedb, but it would not affect the persistent lvldb.

Comment: In versions prior to 1.9.20 it didn't delete old trie state from disk instead it will keep them in memory. And will discard them from memory, so states to be discarded never reach persistent storage.